# How do you access a generic nested inside another generic?

Tags: java, generics

I have some code from a professor with the following classes:

```
public class ModifyableTree<A extends Comparable<? super A>> implements Parent<Tree<A>> {...}
```

and

```
public interface Parent<A> {
    abstract public void updateChild(A oldChild, A newChild);
    abstract public int size();
}
```

and

```
public abstract class Tree<A extends Comparable<? super A>> implements Iterable<A>
```

The problem I'm having is that `A` in the parameter of the `updateChild()` method in `Parent<A>` refers to `<Tree<A>>` so I can't find a way of defining a method that returns the `A` from `Tree<A>`.

How is a generic within a generic accessed like this? Also what is this sort of thing called, and what does `<A extends Comparable<? super A>>` actually mean?

Comment: Maybe it's just crazy talk, but shouldn't `ModifyableTree<A>` implement `Tree<A>`?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `ModifiableTree`?

Comment: public abstract class Tree<A extends Comparable<? super A>> implements Iterable<A>

This is how Tree<A> is defined

(I'll add it to the question). And yes Modifyable looks like a consistent spelling mistake in the whole project (Modifiable).

Comment: Just to get this straigt... you want to access the `A` form `Parent<Tree<A>>` within `Parent`? If this is your question then I think you are out of luck. I do not think that you can enforce a class to be generic (which basically is, what you want), to access it's type parameter within another generic class.

Comment: @Turing85 That is what I'm trying to do yes. If it's not possible then why has the code been written in this way? I don't understand the advantages of using `implements Parent<Tree<A>>`

Answer (score 0):

```
<A extends Comparable<? super A>>
```

Type A has to be extended by Comparable sample:

```
public class A extends Comparable<T>.....
```

and `Comparable<? super A>` say that the type of Comparable has to be a class which hierarchical is above `A`

but I think [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html) will help you more.

Comment: Ah it's called a bounded wildcard - that's a very useful link thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need `A`?  Whoever instantiates you has told you what `A` is.

```
public class ModifyableTree<A extends Comparable<? super A>> implements Parent<Tree<A>> {
    private Tree< A > currentChild;

    // hard to tell what the semantics of updateChild are supposed to be
    @Override
    public void updateChild( Tree< A > oldChild, Tree< A > newChild ) {
        currentChild = newChild;
    }
    @Override
    public int size() { ... }

    // for example
    public A opQuestionMethod() {
        return currentChild.iterator().next();
    }
}
```

Perhaps what the OP is trying to do is insist that `A` always be replaced by something which is actually a `Tree< B >` for some other type `B`.  In that case the declaration of `Parent` requires a constraint:

```
interface Parent< B, A extends Tree< B > > {
    void updateChild( A oldChild, A newChild );
    int size();
    B getLabel( int iIndex );
}
```

Comment: I wanted to add this: `public A getLabel(int index)` to the interface Parent<A> as it's in the implementing classes as an abstract method, but A refers to `<Tree<A>>` and I don't understand how to access the generic A within `Tree<A>` when A refers to `<Tree<A>>` as a whole in the interface.

Comment: If `Parent< A >` has a method `A getLabel( int index )`, then `ModifyableTree< B >` needs to implement `Tree< B > getLabel( int index )`.  The `A` in each case means something completely different so use a different variable to stop being confused.

Comment: Hi @Judge, I tried `Parent<B>` with method `B getLabel(int index)` and `public class ModifyableTree<A extends Comparable<? super A>> implements Parent<Tree<A>> `. I swapped A and B from your example because it took way less refactoring. I'm finding that `Parent<B>` is not compiling with the error 'cannot find symbol - class A` for the line `abstract public A getLabel();`. Note it does the same if getLabel returns `Tree<A>` as you suggested, although I was trying to get at the generic `A` not return the object of `Tree<A>`.

Comment: I have edited my answer based on my best guess of what you're actually trying to do.